# How to show deployment log when deploying by using firebase tool in program (no CLI)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-tools

I have a question about deployment with firebase-tools module.
I'd like to deploy firebase by using firebase-tools node module and I succeeded to deploy this way.
However the deployment from firebase-tools module didn't show deployment logs.

In CLI case, we can see the deployment log that shows which deployment was done.
So how can I see the deployment logs in program case?

Comment: Are you saying that you used firebase-tools programmatically, not via the CLI, and you want the same status updates that you see output by the CLI?

Comment: Yes! I need programmatically deployment  and status update logging

Comment: I suggest you post this as an issue (feature request) on the firebase-tools GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: OK! I will post it. thank you.